# An error occurred while calling o98.getDynamicFrame. Exception thrown in awaitResult:

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

this is the error that i'm getting. I need to refactor the code according to SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate(). I tried refactoring but it didn't help.

```
FutureWarning: Deprecated in 3.0.0. Use SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() instead.

import logging
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.function import when,lit

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
USER_NAME = 'user'
PASSWORD = 'password'
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.SparkSession
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

def get_df(table: str):
    conn_options = {"url":"redshift-url",
    "user":USER_NAME, "password":PASSWORD,"dbtable": db_table,
    "redshiftTmpDir": args["TempDir"],"aws_iam_role":"role"
    }
    return glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("redshift", conn_options).to_DF()
```

Comment: What glue version are you using? Also that is a warning not a error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should get your spark context by using the SparkSession builder:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]") \
                    .appName('YourAppName') \
                    .getOrCreate()
sc=spark.sparkContext
```